# How to get redshift to add current time for a field specified in copy command

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a TSV file that I want to load into redshift via the copy command.

I want one of the fields in the table to be a timestamp that registers the time the row was loaded.

I have defined a field like this:

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This works fine if I insert into this row at the psql command line, without specifying a value for this column - it defaults to the current timestamp as expected.

However, what can I have in my TSV file in that column that will cause redshift to default to the current timestamp?

If I use `\N` in my TSV, then I just get a NULL in the ts field.

On the other hand, if I define my column as NOT NULL

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

then I get an error from the COPY command that I can't insert NULL values into a NOT NULL field.

On mysql, mysql would convert a NULL value into the current timestamp, but redshift's behaviour is to throw an error.

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: I have thought of a crude work around. For the \N field in the TSV, I will create a column in redshift called dummy and ignore it. But I will add a column to the redshift table that will not have a corresponding value in the TSV file, and this will update with the current time as expected. It's annoying to have the extra redundant dummy column. Of course I could just change the TSV, but that requires a lot of rework for other reasons.

Comment: can you post process the file once it is loaded to add the value?

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head over this for a while and found one partial workaround: you can have `ts` column as the last column of your table and the TSV file with all the other columns but this one. The file will be read with the columns that exist and loaded into the consecutive list of columns with the same width in the target table, leaving all columns beyond that width with default values, i.e. you can have `id | ts` table and load the file with `id` only and `ts` will take the default. The current timestamp column is typically a metadata column, so it's ok to place it at the end of the table.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is pretty much what I have ended up doing. If you specify the column names in the copy command, it doesn't even have to be at the end I think (you probably know this but for other readers). So if you have a,b,c,ts you can just do copy mytable(a,b,c) and any other fields will load their defaults.